# Are one dimensional std::string arrays technically a matrix?

Tags: arrays, string, matrix, c++17, abstract

I'm writing some code and just wanted to perfect some of programmings abstract ideas. Here is where I am and what I'm asking about:

In c++ we have the data type `std::string`. This data type is basically an advanced pointer which has member functions and variables.

When you use a string array like so: `std::string test[5];` would the string technically be labeled a matrix? The reason I'm wondering this is because with `std::string` you are able to specify individual characters of a regular string by using:

`std::string hello = "Hello"; std::cout<<hello[3];`

output would be:

`l`

This output works when you declare a normal `std::string`. With this stated; when you have:

`std::string hello2[2] = {"hello", "world"}; std::cout<<hello2[0][2]<<hello2[1][3];`

the output of this should be: `ll`

**With all of this information true, would a one dimensional std::string array be considered a matrix?**

Comment: A better analogue would be an array of pointers, e.g. `char *hello2[2] = { "hello", "world" }`. And no that's not really a matrix except in the loosest sense possible.

Comment: Is there any added benefits to using using the string over the char pointer; does the matrix have to be a literal one in order to function properly? The use of std::string seems like it would enable your functions to have less parameters.

Comment: This is the same as asking if as `std::string` is an array of characters (so an array of that is a matrix of characters). I do not think most people would consider a string an array of characters. There are differences in properties and operations.

Comment: does this mean that the values `'A'` and `"A"` have two different ASCII representations?

Comment: `'A'` is an integer with value 65. `"A"` is an array `{65, 0}`. (Ignoring EBCDIC, etc.)

Comment: Typically when you say “matrix” it means a specific thing. It means you have a rectangular array of numeric values. An array of strings wouldn’t be called a matrix. You might call it a ragged array, but more typically you’d call it an array of strings. When you’re naming things you typically don’t pierce layers of abstraction. But this is not a hard and fast rule, it’s just a convention, and there’s not a straightforward set of rules for how we name things. So just for now, know that if you call an array of strings a matrix, it will confuse and mislead people.

Comment: @AJaB: "*be considered a matrix*" By whom? By what standard? A 1D array could "be considered a matrix" if you have the right tools for accessing it. The thing which most defines what an object is is how you intend to use it. Strings are arrays of characters, but they're not often *treated* as arrays of characters. They're usually treated as values that have some meaning.

Comment: All of my Ideas are being thought of in the context of encryption algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix is a rectangular array of numbers or other mathematical objects for which operations such as addition and multiplication are defined ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics])). When it comes single dimensional std::string arrays, the property that they would be always **rectangular** does not hold. For example, you can have the following:

```
std::string strNames[] = { "David", "Bob", "Yana" };
```

For the aforementioned array, the value `strNames[1][3]` is not well defined. In case of a matrix, if the first column has 5 values, then all other rows should have 5 columns as well, which may or may not be the case with one dimensional std::string arrays. Therefore, you cannot say that one dimensional std::string arrays are matrices as well.

Comment: A square is a rectangle but a rectangle isn't a square. In the context of matrices within programming, a char array[3][3] is the square while std::string array[3] = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"} is the rectangle!

Comment: @AJaB It’s not the case of one meeting the criteria. For std::string to be called a matrix in general, all of them should at all times meet the criteria, which we know is not the case. You cannot declare single dimension std::string matrices as well because one out of so many meets the criteria.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to declare a signal dimensional by simply using the normal std::string? A string is basically a pointer; which usually points to an array. I feel as though it's safe to say that `std::string str`, when declared normally, is a pointer to an array. While a `std::string str[]` is a pointer to a matrix.

Comment: @user6090272 The question specifically inquires about “one dimensional std::string arrays” and not simple std::string. I know how the std::string works internally, but as the OP had inquired about the string arrays, that’s why I used arrays. I have taken the following piece of code from what the OP has posted in his question :std::string hello2[2] = {"hello", "world"};. It specifically talks about arrays of strings.